# I wanted to find the total of a list, but an error occurred

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, sum

I wanted to find the total sum of `cost`, but after  I added the `[30]`, an error message came up.
This is a section of my code:

```
cost = [['Lounge', 70], ['Bedroom', 70], ['Bathroom', 70], [30]]
print("£", sum(c[1] for c in cost))
```

This is what came up before the error message:

```
Cost: [['Lounge', 70], ['Bedroom', 70], ['Bathroom', 70], [30]]
Total cost:
```

This is the error message that came up:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "G:\Dell download may15\Documents\Qadir's file\Putteridge High School\GCSE years\Year 11\Computing\Coding\Python\CA folder\customer.py", line 93, in <module>
    print("£", sum(c[1] for c in cost))
  File "G:\Dell download may15\Documents\Qadir's file\Putteridge High School\GCSE years\Year 11\Computing\Coding\Python\CA folder\customer.py", line 93, in <genexpr>
    print("£", sum(c[1] for c in cost))
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last list on the list doesn't have a second item.

Comment: This should be a comment @Mohammed Aouf ZOUAG's answer is more useful since it pointed out the problem and provided a solution

Answer (score 1):

You get the error because `c[1]` refers to the second item in your *nested lists*, & your **last** *nested list* has only one item, hence you get the error.

Here's a possible fix:

```
cost = [['Lounge', 70], ['Bedroom', 70], ['Bathroom', 70], [30]]
# Sum all the integers within the nested lists
print("£", sum(num for l in cost for num in l if type(num) == int))
```

**Output:**

```
£ 240
```

Comment: Thanks, this is useful!

Answer (score 1):

Decided to post another answer with a list comprehension that dosen't loop twice since you already know that your nested lists are not equal in length

```
lister = cost = [['Lounge', 70], ['Bedroom', 70], ['Bathroom', 70], [30]]

print(sum([a[0] if isinstance(a[0], int) else a[1] for a in lister]))
```

it's a bad idea to use type to check if a variable is an int you're better off with `isinstance` or trying to convert it to an `int` and catching the exception if it's not an int

Answer (score 1):

To avoid the `IndexError` with lists of variable length, you can just get the last item by using the index -1. I think this is the most elegant solution if the numbers you want to add are always at the last position of your lists.

Demo:

```
>>> cost = [['a', 'b', 1], [2], ['a', 3]]
>>> sum(c[-1] for c in cost)
6
```